# Display gridview with combobox dropdownlist without database

Tags: c#, gridview, combobox

I am new in C# and I would like to populate Gridview based on combobox dropdown list items. for instance, I would like to display gridview where the status column value in gridview is 1.
Is there any way to do it without database?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQbwB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean filtering of grid rows based on the Combo box selected value?
If yes, we can make use of the "SelectedIndexChanged" event of the combo box and filter the rows of the grid and reassign the new data source.
In a windows forms application I have added a combo box and a grid view as shown in the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8kRv.png)

And the code behind is as shown below

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataTable table;        
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Data for the grid
        table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("First Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Last Name");
        table.Columns.Add("Gender");
        table.Rows.Add("Adarsh", "Kumar", Gender.Male);
        table.Rows.Add("Ajay", "Murthy", Gender.Male);
        table.Rows.Add("Akshatha", "Kulkarni", Gender.Female);
        table.Rows.Add("Ananya", "Bhat", Gender.Female);

        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
        comboBox1.Items.Add("All");
        comboBox1.Items.Add(Gender.Male);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(Gender.Female);
        comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboBox1.Items[0];
    }

    // Combo box selection index changed event
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        switch (comboBox.SelectedItem)
        {
            case "All":
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                    break;
                }

            case Gender.Male:
                {
                  //Method call to filter the rows                        
                    GetMaleRows();
                    break;
                }

            case Gender.Female:
                {
                  //Method call to filter the rows  
                    GetFemaleRows();
                    break;
                }

            default:
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                break;


        }

    }

   //Method to filter female rows and assigned to grid
    private void GetFemaleRows()
    {
        DataTable femaleTable = table.Clone();

        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (table.Rows[i]["Gender"].Equals(Gender.Female))
            {
                DataRow dataRow = femaleTable.NewRow();
                dataRow = table.Rows[i];
                femaleTable.Rows.Add(dataRow.ItemArray);
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = femaleTable;
    }

   //Method to filter male rows and assigned to grid
    private void GetMaleRows()
    {
        DataTable maleTable = table.Clone();

        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (table.Rows[i]["Gender"].Equals(Gender.Male))
            {
                DataRow dataRow = maleTable.NewRow();
                dataRow = table.Rows[i];
                maleTable.Rows.Add(dataRow.ItemArray);
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = maleTable;
    }
}

public static class Gender
{
    public const string Male = "Male";
    public const string Female = "Female";
}
```

When "All" is selected in the combo box, All rows are displayed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfnAs.png)

When "Male" is selected in the combo box, All rows with Gender = "Male" displayed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ9do.png)

When "Female" is selected in the combo box, All rows with Gender = "Female" displayed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTkEO.png)